# How to address inflated Joel Test score?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

There is a posting on Stack Overflow Careers that claims to score 12 out of 12 on the [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html). This is not true according to developers that I've talked to at the company.  What's the recommended course of action?  If I "flag a problem" will the company see who flagged it?

Comment: Maybe they just disagree with #8 -- or they discuss it a lot. Loudly.

Comment: Please link that particular posting.

Comment: @KenWhite It seems OP is trying to maintain some degree of discretion in order to submit the dispute as anonymously as possible. That's why he's asking for the recommended course of action instead of providing evidence here. Why does he need to provide any evidence to you? Are you in a position of authority on the Careers site?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to keep in mind that the job posts on Careers are paid advertisements.

[image]

Like all paid advertisement, the company paying for the ad is likely to stretch the truth a bit in order to reap the most benefit from their investment.

It should be common sense to approach any job ad with a little caution.

When the ad says "we're grrreat!" it is a biased self evaluation at best, and a stretch at worst.

Expect all of these ads to make claims that aren't perfectly accurate on all points.

---

It appears that this issue has come up before: [Company is cheating in its Joel Test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170215/217863)

Apparently if you flag the ad, the team may [reach out to the company if they agree that something looks fishy.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170325/217863)

Comment: Thanks, this is great info.  And I didn't notice the difference between Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange, which would explain why that first link didn't show up in my searches.  I guess I posted this in the wrong place, sorry.

Comment: Depends on the inaccurate items... most on this list are fairly objective; "Do you use source control?", "Do you have a bugs database?", "Do you make daily builds?". Misrepresenting these is not the same as saying something along the lines of "we're a great company!".

Comment: @aw04 True, but I don't think SE will generally have a reliable way of verifying such claims.

Comment: @JLRishe Yes, on that much I agree. Not worth the effort and I assume the purpose of the ads is to generate revenue. Never make generating revenue harder than it needs to be :)

Comment: This isn't really a valid argument. False advertising can be illegal.

Answer (score -6):

*Don't*.

People lie all the time. People misrepresent themselves and their organisations all the time.

You can't start policing every piece of text on the internet, assigning it some "truth" value.

Who gets to decide what is "true" and what is not? You? Me? No.

If the company is lying egregiously then prospective employees will hopefully spot this at the interview stage. Yes, it's a shame that they have been misled up to that point, but that's life. Assigning yourself a "policeman" role is only going to make things worse. It's none of our business.

Comment: This entire answer must be uncomfortable reading for anyone used to the way things work on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BoltClock: What do you mean?

Comment: Statements such as "You can't start policing every piece of text" "that's life" "It's none of our business" must make Stack Overflow voters and flaggers uncomfortable.

Comment: @BoltClock: It's a completely different thing though, isn't it? Voting on technical content and flagging objectively spammy or inappropriate content is not the same as making value judgements on the accuracy of advertisements for organisations about which the vast, vast, vast majority of readers will have no realistic prospect of authority on the matter! You can be experienced in C++ and have qualifications in C++, but you can't be experienced in "what company X says their working environment is like", unless you worked there yourself. _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ With so few being able to claim that experience, it seems unreasonable to expect mass voting to do its job effectively here. No matter how much of my answer you reproduce in quoted form in the comments :P

Comment: I tend to agree with Lightness here. Even if you don't agree it's none of our business - how would you reliably prove that a company is lying on one or several items of the Joel test? Short of an affidavit from someone who works there (which is never going to happen for obvious reasons)?

Comment: I think this might be the first thing I've seen by Lightness Races in Orbit that had a negative score.

Comment: I momentarily slammed the downvote as I read your answer thinking, "WTF are you saying!!" ... until I reached @Pekka웃's comment!

Comment: Speaking as a librarian, part of whose job is to help students sort out the signal to noise ratio, while one might argue that it is okay to allow falsity to appear as a teaching tool, I would have to argue that the LESS crap we find on the internet the better.  Mine is a vote for quality and *not* allowing lies to persist unchallenged.

Comment: @nomistic: I think you're missing the point of this answer. Please refer to its fourth paragraph: _"Who gets to decide what is "true" and what is not? You? Me? No."_

Comment: 'You can't start policing every piece of text on the internet, assigning it some "truth" value' - you can research it and assign an empirical value.  I guess I'm not as cynical yet as to say "that's life."   It doesn't have to be if we can learn from others' experiences and prevent new people from having to suffer from the lies of a bad employer.   I would hope that if someone had a bad experience, they'd share it with others to prevent them from making the same mistake.  (I speak from personal experience;  I had cases where I wish I had been warned).

Comment: In other words, life isn't that long.

Comment: @nomistic: I'm being cynical yes but the basis of that is an observation of infeasibility. Pekka said it best.

Comment: I guess it not our role to "police" as a policy.   We don't need to hunt down each and every lie,  However, I believe it's responsible to share evidence that is contrary to a claim one knows it to be false, for the same reason we would stop a blind person from wandering in front of an out of control truck.